# wp_enqueue_script in action hook wp_print_scripts

Tags: wordpress

In  the WordPress documentation page for the function [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), it is clearly written:

> **Note**: This function will not work if it is called from a wp_head action, as the  tags are output before wp_head runs. Instead, call wp_enqueue_script from an init action function (to load it in all pages), template_redirect (to load it in public pages only), or admin_print_scripts (for admin pages only). **Do not use wp_print_scripts (see here for an explanation)**.

**Do not use wp_print_scripts action** is what I want to highlight, but do a simple google search on "How to include Javscript in WordPress". You will find most of examples are using **wp_print_scripts** action to call **wp_enqueue_script**.  And it seems like everyone is ok with it.

So am I missing or misunderstanding something here?

---

**EDIT**

The codex has been modified. It now says:

> This function will not work if it is called from a wp_head or wp_print_scripts actions, as the files need to be enqueued before those actions are run. See the Usage section for the correct hooks to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I been there lots of times. The short answer is all those guys that print script requests are all wrong or as some folks suggest it is faster not to use wp_enqueue_script but to load everything dynamically with [Modernizr.load](http://www.modernizr.com/) ([yesnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/)) or any other js loader lib.

My recommendation would be to stick with wp_enqueue_script as the best practice, but if you are developing themes for mobile, or you are extremely worried about speed and not bloating your browser with requests, I really recommend to load everything dynamically with a single js file (that you may call with wp_enqueue_script). Even consider inlining everything out and not loading jQuery but zepto.js or so.

Many developers do this terrible practice of loading everything printed, not only bad taste, but terrible for experienced theme developers I might say :S

For example thematic and several other blank themes rely on this practices and this truncates development speed with childthemes.

If you are not sure about wp_enqueue_script just give the wordpress codex a read. It is thoroughly documented.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
However, my question is actually 
Where should we call wp_enqueue_script ? 
In the codex, It is written that it is better not call it using wp_print_scripts hook action to call it. But most of people do that. So were they wrong?

Comment: If you are developing a whole new theme, you call wp_enqueue_script in your functions.php file. The same for creating child themes. Every file in a child theme folder is called first than the original theme. As I said, I really recommend you to read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). It is very well documented and you'll find how to call the function. In order to give you a better answer I'd need to know if you are modifying a theme, creating one from scratch or creating a child theme.

Comment: And yes. They are wrong most of the times, except if they are doing mobile development or very into html5. My advice is stick to wp_enqueue_script or load everything dynamically with yepnope.js

Comment: Hi, Yes, I fully agree with you that we should use wp_enqueue_script to include javascript in our themes or plugins.
But my question is where to call them, for example, in a plugin development, most of people will use wp_print_scripts hook to call wp_enqueue_script, but that is wrong according to Codex. So why are developers still doing that?
And yes, I have read codex page again and again and again.

Comment: Maybe because this will load your code before any other thing, its a high priority function, but I am no Wordpress contributor to tell you why very technically speaking ;)